# Solving linear equation systems with complex coefficients and variables

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

How would one solve a complex equation system solely using a cartesian representation of complex numbers by hand? For instance, take the following linear equation system:

$(1+i)z_1 - z_2 = i$

$(1-i)z_1 + (1+i)z_2 = 1$

This system contains both complex variables and complex coefficients. Is it even possible to solve an equation system like this? How would one go about it? Does it have multiple solutions since it includes complex numbers?

Comment: You solve it just like you ever solved a system of linear equations.   Either elimination of substitution.  Don't let the complex coefficients scare you, they are just numbers.

Comment: "Is it even possible to solve an equation system like this?" Yes, definitely, for any field $K$ we can solve $a_{11}z_1+a_{12}z_2=b_1,  a_{21}z_1+a_{22}z_2=b_2$ as matrix system $Ax=b$, for coefficients in $K$. Linear algebra works in particular for the field $K=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Bye_World In principle that's true, but it's bad advice: a $2 \times 2$ system is easy (if you're not afraid of doing arithmetic with complex numbers), a $4 \times 4$ is complicated.

Comment: @Bye_World The real and imaginary parts of $(1+i)z_1 - z_2 = i$ give you equations in three of the four variables, the real and imaginary parts of $(1-i) z_1 + (1+i) z_2 = 1$ have all four variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1+i)z_1-z_2 = i\\
(1-i)z_1 + (1+i) = 1$

multiply the first equation by $(1+i)$, and add the two equations together.

$(1+i)^2z_1-(1+i)z_2 = i(1+i)\\
(1-i)z_1 + (1+i)z_2 = 1$

multiply out the complex numbers

$2i z_1-(1+i)z_2 = -1+i\\
(1-i)z_1 + (1+i)z_2 = 1$

adding the two equations

$(1+i)z_1 = i\\
z_1 = \frac {i}{1+i}$

multiply top and bottom by the complex conjugate

$z_1 = \frac {1 + i}2$

substitute into the original equation:

$(1+i)\frac {1 + i}2-z_2 = i\\
i-z_2 = i\\
z_2 = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Matrices with complex entries can be solved just as matrices with real entries.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1+i&-1&i\\
      1-i&1+i&1
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Reduce the matrix to RREF, using the exact same methods as real matrices. The only difference will be that you may have to do a bit of complex arithmetic.

In this case, you should end up with something like:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&0&i/(i+1)\\
      0&1&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: treat $z_1$ and $z_2$ like normal real variables and solve for them. Here if you multiply the first equations by (1+i) you will get:

$(1+i)^2z_1 - (1+i)z_2 = i(1+i)$

$(1-i)z_1 + (1+i)z_2 = 1$

Add both equations:

$$\left[(1+i)^2+(1-i) \right]z_1=1+i(1+i) \implies z_1 = \frac{1+i(1+i)}{\left[(1+i)^2+(1-i) \right]}.$$

Plug this into one of the equations and solve for $z_2$.